Calculate the correct amount after doing a Discount and Contract weight
I have this code inside a .net core console application:-
var currentDate = startdate;

while (currentDate <= enddate)
{
    // Get the days in the current month
    var daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(currentDate.Year, currentDate.Month);

    // Calculate the number of days within the current month
    var monthStart = currentDate;
    var monthEnd = new DateTime(currentDate.Year, currentDate.Month, daysInMonth);
    if (monthEnd > enddate) monthEnd = enddate;

    var daysInCurrentMonth = Convert.ToDecimal(Math.Truncate((monthEnd - monthStart).TotalDays + 1));

    // Proportion of the amount for this month
    var monthlyAmount = decimal.Parse((daysInCurrentMonth / totalDays).ToString()) * Amount;

    // Apply discount if applicable
    monthlyAmount = Math.Round((Discount != null ? monthlyAmount * (1 - (Decimal.Parse(Discount.ToString()) / 100)) : monthlyAmount),3);

    // Add to the result list
    monthlyAmounts.Add(

       (ContractType,
        monthStart,
        monthEnd,
        monthStart.Month.ToString(),
        monthStart.Year,
        monthlyAmount,
        NetworkID,
        NetworkTitle,
        MediumTitle,
        (MediumID != null ? MediumID.ToString() : null),
        BookingCalendarID,
        BookingCalendarIDSalesRepIDMap
            .SingleOrDefault(a => a.Key == BookingCalendarID).Value, daysInCurrentMonth, totalDays, monthlyAmount)
    );

    // Move to the next month
    currentDate = monthEnd.AddDays(1);
}

Where the amount currency is JOD which have max of 3 decimals.
My question is about this 2 lines of code:-
var monthlyAmount = decimal.Parse((daysInCurrentMonth / totalDays).ToString()) * Amount;
    
// Apply discount if applicable
monthlyAmount = Math.Round((Discount != null ? monthlyAmount * (1 - (Decimal.Parse(Discount.ToString()) / 100)) : monthlyAmount),3);

so am I doing the correct calculation? for example i have a contract which start from 22/10/2024 till 4/11/2024, with amount of 1000 JOD (which has 3 decimals) & Discount of 15%. so when i want to calculate the contract amount for November it will be as follow:-
monthlyAmount = 4/14 * 1,000 = 285.7142857142857
monthlyAmount = Math.Round(285.7142857142857 * 0.85,3) = 242.857 JOD
Also when I do the calculation for October i will get 607.142.. But when i sum 242.857 +  607.142 = 849.999 .. so there is a loss of .001 JOD.. so how i can fix this?
Thanks

Why are you doing so much .ToString() and decimal.Parseing? Why not just = daysInCurrentMonth / totalDays * Amount; and Discount * 100?

@gunr2171 but this will not solve the issue , am i correct?

It would help a lot if you [edit] your post with a simplified version of your code (such as this). Please ensure you show example inputs, expected outputs, and actual outputs. See [mre].

Why would you expect any OTHER result?
You are specifically rounding to 2 decimal placed (at least in the large block you wrote) - so you must expect there to be some rounding-errors.
Counter-example: Given the value 0.01 and split it in 3, then rounded to 3 decimal places, and then summed back up - what number do you expect? 0.01 again? No. 0.01/3 => 0,00333333... rounded to 3 decimal places is 0,003 and then summed up again is 0,009
When you round you lose information - or it wouldnt be rounding

Don't store rounded values, and only round a single time at the end for display purposes. Your code also makes a potentially dangerous assumption that currentDate is always the first of the month. monthStart should be something like new DateTime(currentDate.Year, currentDate.Month, 1)  code like if (monthEnd > enddate) monthEnd = enddate; is really confusing, it's no longer guaranteed to be "month end" at that point so the rest of the code loses all informational meaning.

@ABaumstumpf sorry it should be round to 3 not 2 ,  i missed type it when i format the code inside stackoverflow question

@StevePy i am only doing the round at the end of the calculation. the other are only Parsing numbers to decimals as i got error on dividing int with double

@StevePy no the currentDate is the start date of the contract ,, i am not doing this assumption that the start date of the contract will always be the first day of the month /.. how did you observe this?

by this line.  var monthStart = currentDate;  If it isn't the month start, it shouldn't be called "monthStart".  I mean your issue is probably just a case of don't round more often than you need to, and avoid storing rounded values to consolidate into new rounded values, but reading your code based on the naming convention it could easily lead to problems hidden by confusing naming in terns of whether counting parts of months, whole months, or simply a period of days.

@StevePy yes you are correct the naming is bit confusing.. but the currentDate is actually the start date of the contract and/or the start date of the month incase the contract span multiple months

"Also when I do the calculation for October i will get 607.142" - how? 10/14*850 = 607.143 when rounded to 3 dp.

i just plucked the code into vs and removed all the conversions and calculated everything on a double-type basis. After calculation i get the required 850 JOD.
here's the code i used (had to add some variables for execution):
DateTime startdate = new DateTime(2024,10,22);
DateTime enddate = new DateTime(2024,11,4);
List<double> monthlyAmounts = new List<double>();
double Discount = 15.0d;
double Amount = 1000.0d;

var currentDate = startdate;
double totalDays = enddate.Subtract(startdate).TotalDays+1;

while (currentDate <= enddate)
{
// Get the days in the current month
var daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(currentDate.Year, currentDate.Month);

// Calculate the number of days within the current month
var monthStart = currentDate;
var monthEnd = new DateTime(currentDate.Year, currentDate.Month, daysInMonth);
if (monthEnd > enddate) monthEnd = enddate;

var daysInCurrentMonth = Math.Truncate((monthEnd - monthStart).TotalDays + 1);

// Proportion of the amount for this month
var monthlyAmount = (daysInCurrentMonth / totalDays) * Amount;

// Apply discount if applicable
monthlyAmount = Math.Round((Discount != null ? monthlyAmount * (1 - (Discount / 100)) : monthlyAmount), 3);

// Add to the result list
monthlyAmounts.Add(monthlyAmount);

// Move to the next month
currentDate = monthEnd.AddDays(1);
}

i assume all the type conversions may have lost a little bit of the precision during the calculation. if you know that you have to work with decimal numbers, try to base all required integers also on a decimal base to avoid conversion loss :)
